# Abrir archivo archivo atraves de una ruta en java

Tags: java

Uso el siguiente código para llamar a la ruta:

```
String url= "\"C:\\users\\Jose\\Documents\\video\"";

ProcessBuilder p = ProcessBuilder();
p.command("cmd.exe","\c",url);
```

NOTA: este código me funciona perfecto, me llama la dirección del archivo sea vídeo o sea un programa, pero quiero colocar una ruta relativa. Es decir quiero que mi programa al llevarlo a otra maquina siga abriendo los archivos.

¿Como hago para abrir la dirección al colocar mi programa en otra maquina?

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara. Quieres siempre ejecutar la carpeta Video sin importar donde este instalada la aplicacion?

Comment: Si quiero poder abrir el video sin importar donde este instalada , pero claro instalar el programa en otra maquina la ruta deja de ser la misma y no me llama el video

Answer (score 1):

Prueba de esta forma:

Creamos una instancia File de la siguiente manera:

`File file = new File();`

para así poder tener acceso a los meta datos del sistema de 
archivos, y con la clase

`System.getProperty`

recuperamos la propiedad que le 
 estamos indicando, en este caso se trata del nombre de usuario del sistema 
 "user.name" esto nos devolverá el nombre de usuario actual

```
File user = new File(System.getProperty("user.name"));

String url ="C:\\Users\\" + user + "\\Documents\\video\\";
```

Comment: Hola @להוסיף אַבְרָהָם, bienvenido a [es.so]! ¡Gracias por tu aporte! En el sitio intentamos tener respuestas con la mayor calidad posible. La idea no es mostrar solamente un fragmento de código, sino además explicar por qué esto funcionaría. ¿Qué hace este código? ¿Por qué o cómo solucionaría el problema expuesto en la pregunta? ¿Y realmente crees que la aplicación estaría instalada en esta carpeta en cualquir sistema? En [answer] podrás leer algunos consejos. ¿Podrías **[edit]** tu respuesta agregando algo más de información?